# ¿Como poner una etiqueta de audio dentro de un If en php?

Tags: php, html

He intentado varias cosas para que funcione ya que en mi localhost me da error 500, le quite comillas, le quite el echo, cambie el mpeg por mp3, pero sigue sin funcionar dentro del php, solo funciona por fuera.

```
<?php

    if ($_POST){
        $respuesta = $_POST['texto'];

        if ($respuesta == $evaluar){
            echo "Correcto <br/>";
            echo 'Felicidades! '.$_SESSION['admin'];

        }else{
            echo "Intentalo de nuevo<br/>";

           //linea de error
            echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src="negative.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Qué intentas validar con la expresión `if ($_POST){`?? No tiene buena pinta

Comment: hola,  if ($_POST){ funciona para ver que se envio respuesta de un formulario del mismo metodo, todo funciona correctamente, exeptuando la linea echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden> de hecho, si la comento todo funciona correctamente, aunque la quiero añadir como un plus.

Comment: Veo un detalle enorme, ** echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src="negative.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>";** cambia las comillas dobles por las simples dentro de tu echo

Comment: Las comillas dobles dentro de las comillas dobles del echo van a romper la cadena. Escápalas o cámbialas por simples :)

Comment: Les agradesco muchisimo!!, nunca lo pense realmente, soy estudiante de preparatoria con malos profesores, asi que perdon por la mala pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente el único problema que observo son las comillas. Intente con alguna de estas opciones:

```
<!-- funciona solo si el valor del atributo no tiene espacios -->
echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src=negative.mp3 type=audio/mp3></audio>";

echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src='negative.mp3' type='audio/mp3'></audio>";

echo "<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src=\"negative.mp3\" type=\"audio/mp3\"></audio>";

echo '<audio controls autoplay hidden><source src="negative.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>';
```